# how to add option with its optgroup using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have created code for add and remove option from select boxs.Its working fine but i want to add option with it's optgroup text and remove with its optgroup.Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/8ybf7nke/22/

my jsp :

```
<div>
<select name="SelectFeatures" id="SelectFeatures" multiple="multiple"
    style="height: 315px;width:200px" onchange="Move()">
    <option>Lesson</option>
    <option value="about myself">about myself</option>
    <option>about yourself</option>
    <option>Game</option>
    <option>about me game</option>
    <option>Worksheet</option>
    <option>content</option>
    <option>content2</option>
</select>
<select name="SelectedFeatures" id="SelectedFeatures" multiple="multiple"
    style="height: 315px;width:200px" onchange="Move()">

</select>
</div>
```

I am creating optgroup dynamically using below code,

var $options = $('#SelectFeatures option');

```
var $group = null;
$options.each(function(){
    var $option = $(this);
    var text = $option.text();
    if (text === 'Lesson' || text === 'Game' || text == 'Worksheet')
    {
        $group = $('<optgroup label="' + text + '"/>');
        $option.replaceWith($group);
    }
    else
    {
        $group.append($option);
    }
});
```

Someone tell me how to add and remove with its optgroup?

Comment: Since you have a lot of irrelevant code in fiddle, I created [separated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xhbLf7/). In your case, this code should be executed after `<select>` is splitted to groups.

Comment: @Regent great! you did what i need but same time there is not removing selected elements?!

Comment: @Regent how to remove from right side selected option and enable same option in right side?

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it. Here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xhbLf7/1/).

Comment: @Regent wow! great job Mr. Why dont you post your answer here??? I must accept your answer.

Comment: Well, since it is correct now, I should post it as an answer indeed.

Comment: @Regent but there is big problem you have hide the all option not remove so if insert empty select box values to DB even there is previous added values.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. You don't see hidden options, so it looks just the same as options' deletion. Hiding/showing is much easier and faster than appending/removing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67007/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-regent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to copy all `<optgroup>`s and `<option>`s to second `<select>` and to show only selected options in it, hiding all others.

All selected options can be chosen by selecting only visible options.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xhbLf7/1/)

HTML:

```
<select name="SelectFeatures" id="SelectFeatures" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Lesson">
        <option>about myself</option>
        <option>about yourself</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Game">
        <option>about my game</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Worksheet">
        <option>content</option>
        <option>content2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select name="SelectedFeatures" id="SelectedFeatures" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#SelectFeatures optgroup').clone().hide().appendTo('#SelectedFeatures');
    $('#SelectedFeatures option').hide();

    $('#SelectFeatures').on('click', 'option', function()
    {
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        this.disabled = true;
        var thisGroup = $(this).parent();
        var targetGroup = $('#SelectedFeatures optgroup[label="' + thisGroup.attr('label') + '"]');
        targetGroup.show();
        targetGroup.find('option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == thisText; }).show();
    });

    $('#SelectedFeatures').on('click', 'option', function()
    {
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#SelectFeatures option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == thisText; }).prop('disabled', false);
        var thisGroup = $(this).parent();        
        if (thisGroup.find('option:visible').length == 0)
        {
            thisGroup.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Version with options deletion:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xhbLf7/11/).

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $('#SelectFeatures').on('click', 'option', function()
    {
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        var thisGroup = $(this).parent();
        var targetGroup = $('#SelectedFeatures optgroup[label="' + thisGroup.attr('label') + '"]');
        if (targetGroup.length == 0)
        {
            targetGroup = thisGroup.clone();
            targetGroup.find('option').remove();
            var nextGroupsText = thisGroup.nextAll().map(function() { return $(this).attr('label'); }).get();
            var inserted = false;
            $('#SelectedFeatures optgroup').each(function()
            {
                if ($.inArray($(this).attr('label'), nextGroupsText) > -1)
                {
                    targetGroup.insertBefore(this);
                    inserted = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (!inserted)
            {
                $('#SelectedFeatures').append(targetGroup);
            }
        }
        targetGroup.append($(this).clone());
        this.disabled = true;
    });

    $('#SelectedFeatures').on('click', 'option', function()
    {
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        $('#SelectFeatures option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == thisText; }).prop('disabled', false);
        var thisGroup = $(this).parent();
        $(this).remove();
        if (thisGroup.find('option').length == 0)
        {
            thisGroup.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: everything fine but hide() not working in chrome from this line  $('#SelectFeatures optgroup').clone().hide().appendTo('#SelectedFeatures');
     $('#SelectedFeatures option').hide();.why?

Comment: if i use your code there is rising browser compatibility issue.In chrome 34.0 that hide not works and In chrome 37.0 all option hiding when click on single option.so how to fix this?

Comment: @manivasagam well, I only have Chrome 39 (in which code works just fine), so I can't test it. And I don't see any problems in code. It can be Chrome old versions quirks. If it is critical for you, you can try version with options deletion: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xhbLf7/9/)

Comment: this fiddle works fine but i want to add options like left side select box order that means like "Lesson,Games,Worksheet". will this possible in deletion?

Comment: and also that var options = $(this).find('option:visible').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();groups.push($(this).attr('label') + "-" + options.join(',')); not works in chrome

Comment: @manivasagam in correct order: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xhbLf7/11/). About saving: try to remove `:visible` both from `option:visible` and `optgroup:visible` if you use version with options deletion.

Comment: awsome!.why dont you change the code from last fiddle.

Comment: but what about var options = $(this).find('option:visible').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();groups.push($(this).attr('label') + "-" + options.join(','));???

Comment: @manivasagam I added version with deletion to question. About saving options: have you tried to simply remove `:visible` from this line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67185/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-regent).